# Decide if touch position is left, top, right or down from specific point

Tags: java, android

How do I decide if touch position of user input is (more likely) left, top, right or bottom from specific point? I know how to get position of touch, but don't know how to decide which "way" it is.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        //...
    }
    return false;
}
```

Demonstration image:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using math?

Comment: No, since I don't know how to use it for these diagonals.

Comment: @BlackJack Do you need these exact angles? If not, would checking if "this touch is more down than right" suffice?

Comment: @Houseman oh you are right. I couldn't figure it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming those are 45 degree angles, then

```
dy = pointY- currentY
dx = pointX- currentX
if(abs(dy) > abs (dx) && dy <0 ) return bottom
else if(abs(dy) - abs (dx)) return top
else if(dx < 0) return right
else if (dx > 0) return left
else return same point
```

If those aren't 45 degree angles, you're going to have to use trig to figure out where the boundaries are.

Comment: Yes, they are 45° (imaginary, to make bounds of decision areas). Thank you for your solution.